# Check if a (String) variable is well defined - use preprocessor?

Tags: arduino

I am currently developing an Arduino based project involving a password check.

The password is provided as a global variable in the source code. However, the password should only allow certain characters (basically only letters, numbers and just a few special characters).

I want to ensure that no other characters are used - otherwise the code shouldn't compile.

Is there a way (possibly using the preprocessor) to check a String variable for the characters it contains and abort compilation if "illegal" characters are used?

Example code snipplet (probably not necessary, however...):

```
const String password1 = "test"; // should compile
const String password2 = "%$§~^"; // should NOT compile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I do not believe this is possible at the preprocessor level. The C preprocessor cannot inspect strings.

If you were to abandon the Arduino IDE and use a Makefile or shell script, you could do it there.

Something along the lines of:

```
PASSWORD="test"

if [ echo $PASSWORD | grep -e <magic regexp for invalid chars> ]
then
gcc ... -DPASSWORD="$(PASSWORD)"
else
exit 1
fi
```

Another way might be:

```
typedef enum
{
MY_A 'a',
MY_B 'b',
MY_C 'c',
// etc. for all allowed characters
} my_charset;

const my_charset *password = {MY_P, MY_A, MY_S, MY_S, MY_W, MY_O, MY_R, MY_D};
```

Comment: good idea - I also thought about that. However, for my personal use I can ensure that I only use "allowed" characters myself. Therefore I need the pw check just for 2 reasons: (1) if other people use it (eg. if I upload the code somewhere) (2) for reasons of "code elegancy". However, I fear reason (1) also implies that using a Makefile or a shell script is an additional obstacle that will distract people from using my code.

Comment: just for reasons of completeness: would it work with a char-array?

Comment: You can still do something at runtime. Eg. if password is bad, flash LED and refuse to startup

Comment: also a good workaround. However, it's a pity that there is no straight forward solution. Compiling and uploading a code that is obviously not executable feels wrong as the error should already be detected by the compiler.

Comment: Maybe another way would be to declare a new object that only would take allowed characters.

Comment: this is probably the best one can get... thank you!